# Symbol 'vector' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have the following C++ code in an Eclipse project imported from an existing Makfile-based project:

```
#ifndef LAZY_EVAL_FUNCTOR_
#define LAZY_EVAL_FUNCTOR_

#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

namespace libtensor {

//Forward declaration
template<size_t N,typename T> 
class labeled_sparse_btensor;

typedef std::vector<size_t> block_list; 

//Used to erase other size parameters from contract_eval_functor 
template<size_t N,typename T=double>
class lazy_eval_functor {
public:
    virtual void operator()(labeled_sparse_btensor<N,T>& dest) const = 0;

    //For direct tensors
    virtual void operator()(labeled_sparse_btensor<N,T>& dest,std::vector< block_list >& output_block_lists) const = 0;

    virtual ~lazy_eval_functor() {};
};

} // namespace libtensor

#endif /* LAZY_EVAL_FUNCTOR_ */
```

Despite the fact that the  include is resolved correctly, I still get errors on both lines in which std::vector appears:

```
Symbol 'vector' could not be resolved.
```

I have already added the include path in which std::vector is defined:

[image]

My OS is Mac OS X 10.6 and my gcc version is gcc 4.2.1

Please advise a way to resolve this issue.

EDIT: It seems to do this for other std members to, such as std::map. There is no 'unresolved inclusion' error for the header, but it doesn't find the corresponding class.

Comment: This is a code analysis problem, right? I disabled that feature in Window -> Preferences -> Code Analysis, because the build configuration is already OK. I just don't want to mess around with halfway finished features.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with Eclipse code analysis reporting a (seemingly) erroneous error. I would rather not disable it entirely if there is another way though...

Comment: You declare the type, but do you ever instantiate it anywhere?

Comment: @ZacHowland: yes, in various .C files that include this header.